# How can I use excel to generate sentences from a multitude of possible options?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Right now I have a list of around 100 manholes, and each manhole has 8 different things that could be wrong with it (defects), each of those has 12 positions that they could be at in the manhole (think positions on a clock).

For example a manhole could have 2 holes and 1 leak at 5, 7, and 11 o'clock in the manhole.

In Excel I have a column for every type of defect that, when the defect column and manhole row match up, if the manhole has that defect, the number of defects is manually entered into that cell. If there are no defects, they are all left blank in that row. Then, the number of defects and type of defect is put into a different cell for formatting, so it looks like this: `(2) holes`

The numbers up top along withe at, bench, etc, are all for what I use as references when I'm building my sentences. I reference all the cells individually in order to create a sentence that looks something like this:

> *68409* has *(2) Weepers* *at* *2, 3* *o'clock* *in channel* and *(1) gusher* *at* *3 o'clock* *on bench*

The Italics show what is selected from the sheet. I want Excel to do all the work for me, rather than typing in something like this every time:

```
=C4&" has "&AB4&$AB$1&AN4&" "&$AC$1&" "&AD1&" and "&AE4&$AB$1&AQ4&$AC$1&" "&AE1
```

I'm not sure if Excel can help me at all because there are a lot of references and possibilities. I'm not afraid to have to do some of it myself, like making sure the sentence flows well or even put in heights within the manhole (Cause I need to do that too), but if something could get me started, then that would help a lot.

Thanks!

This is how I tell what time each defect is located at:
[image: This is how I tell what time each defect is located at]

This is what my sheet looks like:
[image: This is what my sheet looks like]

Comment: Sounds like a job for `VLOOKUP`

Comment: Where is this "sentence" supposed to go?  (ie. in which cell is your example formula located?) Also, the formula refers to two different rows. What's the logic behind that? It might make more sense if you can show an example of a few completed rows. Also you might end up having to organize your data better, ie.,one piece of information per cell.

Comment: ...also, it almost seems like a pivot table would be easiest - but that would give you an organized set of data, rather than "sentences".

Comment: @ashleedawg The sentence goes to the right of all the data, just out of the way in its own area. The reason it references two rows is because it needs to grab certain key words like "on bench" or "at" to make the sentences sound more like sentences and not just a blob of words/numbers. The sentence I've shown and its code are both in my question and it refers to 65409 in the images. Sorry if that was confusing!

Comment: Based on your images, the formula you gave would not return the sample sentence shown.  That being said, the concept would work just by putting the formula in that location to the right of the data and dragging down.  However, it looks like you need decision making to get a valid sentence.  Is that your question?